# How to use ptdump

Tags: python, pytables

This is almost certainly another "feel like an idiot" questions, but I'm at a loss here.

Trying to simply get `ptdump` to work (even just `ptdump -h`)

Python 3.4.1 was originally installed on this Windows machine using the Anaconda distribution.

`sys.path` for Python gives me:

```
['', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\python34.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib', 'C
:\\Anaconda3', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packa
ges\\runipy-0.1.0-py3.4.egg', 'C:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-3.6-py
3.4.egg']
```

I can find the tables `ptdump.py` file at:

```
C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tables\scripts
```

How do I actually invoke it / use it though?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ptdump from the windows command line, you need to make sure it is in your PATH environment variable.
try this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tables\scripts
ptdump.py -h
```

Comment: yeah I know. Turns out that it was an issue with the PyTables installation from Anaconda. Submitted a ticket with them and they confirmed and released a fix.